# Presheaves on a complete Segal space

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, model-categories

Let *C* be an $(\infty,1)$-category, incarnated as a complete Segal space, hence in particular a bisimplicial set.  Is there a model structure on the slice category of bisimplicial sets over *C* which presents the $(\infty,1)$-presheaf category of *C*?  Ideally, such a model structure would be Quillen equivalent to the contravariant model structure over a quasicategory incarnation of *C*, and to the projective model structure for simplicial presheaves on a simplicial-category incarnation of *C*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Let $W$ be a complete Segal space, thought of as a simplicial "space" $(W_q)$.  The fibrant objects of your model category will be the fibrations $f:X\to W$ such that for each simplicial operator $\delta:[q]\to [p]$ with $\delta(q)=p$, the evident map from $X_p$ to the pullback of 
$$X_q \xrightarrow{f} W_q \xleftarrow{\delta} W_p$$
is a weak equivalence of spaces.  (**Edit:** in fact, it suffices to require the evident map to the pullback to be a weak equivalence only for $\delta:[0]\to[p]$ with $\delta(0)=p$.)

I worked out some of this years ago, but never finished it; somebody should do this (or perhaps someone has already?).  Lurie has done pretty much exactly the same thing in the context of quasi-categories, in HTT.

Comment: Thanks!  Two questions.  (1) By "fibrations $f\colon X\to W$", do you mean Reedy fibrations?  Or fibrations in the CSS model structure?  (2) Is the "evident map" necessarily itself a fibration (say, if $f$ is a fibration according to your answer to (1))?

Comment: Also, (3) I presume that this model structure is constructed as a localization of some over-model-structure for simplicial spaces over W?  And (4, I guess) does that imply that the weak equivalences between fibrant objects in this model structure are still just the levelwise equivalences?

Comment: (1) I mean Reedy fibration.  It turns out that if W is a CSS, and f is a Reedy fibration with the above property, then X is also a CSS, and thus f (being a Reedy fibration between CSS's) is also a fibration in the CSS model category.  (2) I believe it is a fibration if $\delta$ is injective, but not generally.  (In the condition describing fibrant objects, it actually suffices to require a weak equivalence only in the case $\delta:[0]\to [p]$.) (3) Yup.  (4) Yup.  

Comment: Beautiful!  That's all I could have hoped for.  Someone should really work all of this out and write it up.